# MongoTemplate.findOne by new ObjectId.toHexString returns no result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to query Mongo by a String representation of the ObjectId.toHexString(), and get no result returned, while non generated by ObjectId id's can be found.

In the document the _id is of type **String**

**Document Representation.**

```
{
    "_id" : "100000",
    "name" : "name1",
    "name2" : "name3",
    "_entity" : [
        "industryV6",
        "baseEntity"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "5f8018d5438a5c7cde00101f",
    "name" : "name1",
    "name2" : "name2",
    "_entity" : [
        "industryV6",
        "baseEntity"
    ]
}
```

**code**

```
Query idQuery = new Query();
idQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is("5f8018d5438a5c7cde00101f"));

Document document =  mongoTemplate.findOne(idQuery, Document.class, "dictionary");
```

I already tested in the mongo shell with the help of `db.dictionary.find({_id : "5f8018d5438a5c7cde00101f"})` and I have the result returned.

What could be the problem ?

Is MongoTemplate doing a special conversion when inserting "ObjectId.toHexString()" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using new ObjectId()

```
Query idQuery = new Query();
idQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("5f8018d5438a5c7cde00101f")));

Document document =  mongoTemplate.findOne(idQuery, Document.class, "dictionary");
```